# CSS containers when minmizing the browser it mixed up

Tags: html, css, web, containers

I have start to design a web template and I have faced a problem in containers, whenever I minimize the browser it look mixed and goes in another place. I am trying to make it look like notepad++.

You can check my output here: http://jsfiddle.net/Razor_01100/TLkTt/embedded/result/

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:1000px;
}
#container {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #0096ff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container2 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container3 {
    width: 849px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #313131;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.text-container3 {
    color: white;
}
#footer {

}
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
            </div>
            <div id="container2">
                <div id="nav-wrapper">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">X-Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">X-Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">X-Programming</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">X-Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container3">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: With the HTML and CSS that you provided the output looks like http://jsfiddle.net/jY9cD/

Comment: Can you show images of what your output is currently and what you want?

Comment: i have added jsfiddle output, can you please check it again

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the 2nd edit (which still included the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this, the first is floats, the second is positioning.

You are using floats. These automatically move themselves to fit whatever space they can fill if their total size does not fit the window. Aka, they move if you change the window size and cause undesirable formatting. I would recommend using `display:block` (will put an element on a line of its own) or `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` (to get the same function as floats). You get more control and it is better practice in general.

However, that will not fix the alignment issue, so that goes to part 2, position. Since your wrapper is relative, you can make all the child divs absolute position:

```
#wrapper div{ 
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align: top;
position: absolute; 
}
```

Absolute puts the divs at the exact coordinates you want in relation to the parent. Then manually set the position of the children (#container, #container2, #container3). This will ensure that they will not move no matter how the size of the screen is changed.

```
#container { left: 0px; ... }
#container2 { left: 300px; ... }
#container3 { left: 500px; ... }
```

You might also want to add in "top" (default is 0px), but feel free to play around.

Comment: thank you for the well-explained answer, it is useful but it does not solve my problem,

Answer (score 1):

i think you just  set your wrapper div 
css

```
# wrapper
{
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

i hope this will help

Comment: it doesn't work , thanks

Comment: css.. wrap{
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
width:1024px;
}
 and <body><div id="wrap">your web</div></body> try this i had sort all of these type of problem by this.otherwise sorry ;)